# how to get events in google calendar dialogflow

Tags: google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to get events from my google calendar with dialogflow fullfilment, if i use only console.log i can see in firebase my events ! and if i try to put in dialogflow i got an error in my log [image]
In that picture i got an error with res.data.items, [image]
I don't know how i can get my event in my google calendar, pls help :D

Comment: did you get an answer to that question?